# Write descriptive unit tests

Tags: javascript, python, unit-testing

I'm trying to write unit tests in Python and struggle to find a descriptive way to do things. I have a JavaScript background and I use `mocha` which helps me be descriptive.

This is what I mean by "descriptive":

**foo.js**

```
exports.foo = function (type, isLogged, iOk) {
    if (type === undefined) throw new Error('a cannot be undefined');
    if (isLogged === undefined) throw new Error('b cannot be undefined');
    if (isLogged) {
        if (type === 'WRITER') {
            return isOk ? "writer" : -1;
        } else {
            return "something else"
        }
    }
}
```

**foo.spec.js**

```
describe('#foo()', function () {
    context('when type is undefined', function () {
      ...
    })
    context('when isLogged is undefined', function () {
      ...
    })
    context('when type is defined', function () {
        context('when isLogger is not defined', function () {
         ...
        })
        context('when isLogged is defined', function () {
            context('when type is not WRITER', function () {
             ...
            })
            context('when type is WRITER', function () {
                context('when isOk is true', function () {
                 ...
                })
            })
        }) 
    })
})
```

While when I write unit tests in Python, I end up with somthing like this:

**foo.spec.py**

```
class TestFoo:
    def test_when_type_is_undefined(self):
        ...
    def test_when_isLogged_is_undefined(self):
        ...
    # This test name is too long
    def test_when_type_is_defined_and_isLogged_is_undefined_and_type_is_writer_when_is_ok_is_true(self):
        ...
```

How to structure these test in a better way? What are the best practices regarding descriptive unit testing? Are there good examples of good unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pyspecs](https://github.com/mdwhatcott/pyspecs) to have a more BDD-like syntax in your code.

### Example:

```
from pyspecs import given, when, then, and_, the, this

with given.two_operands:
    a = 2
    b = 3

    with when.supplied_to_the_add_function:
        total = a + b

        with then.the_total_should_be_mathmatically_correct:
            the(total).should.equal(5)

        with and_.the_total_should_be_greater_than_either_operand:
            the(total).should.be_greater_than(a)
            the(total).should.be_greater_than(b)

    with when.supplied_to_the_subtract_function:
        difference = b - a

        with then.the_difference_should_be_mathmatically_correct:
            the(difference).should.equal(1)
```

### Output

```
# run_pyspecs.py

  | • given two operands 
  |   • when supplied to the add function 
  |     • then the total should be mathmatically correct 
  |     • and the total should be greater than either operand 
  |   • when supplied to the subtract function 
  |     • then the difference should be mathmatically correct 

(ok) 6 passed (6 steps, 1 scenarios in 0.0002 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your unit test construction. Unit tests should be very descriptive so it is apparent what the problem is once a test fails. As a developer with little information, the testcase `test_when_type_is_defined_and_isLogged_is_undefined_and_type_is_writer_when_is_ok_is_true` tells me a lot about what went wrong and where to look.

You can make your tests even more descriptive by adding an error message in your `assert` statements, so that when something fails, you know exactly why. For example: "Expected writer to be `ok` but writer was None".

To me, the name of the file that the test is in, the name of the test case, and the assertion message should give a clear path to what code failed and why.

Comment: While I mostly agree with you, if I try to comply with PEP8, the method name cannot exceed 100 characters. How to manage to do both?

Comment: I follow PEP8 almost religiously. However it is a [guideline](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) and not a mandate. If you code makes more sense and is more readable to you this way, then that's the best way for you!

Answer (score 0):

Having meaningful test method names is, of course, important but, when a test name becomes unpractically long and non-readable, you can always provide full test descriptions inside method  [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Here are some [sample tests from the `requests` library](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/tests/test_requests.py#L378):

```
def test_cookielib_cookiejar_on_redirect(self, httpbin):
    """Tests resolve_redirect doesn't fail when merging cookies
    with non-RequestsCookieJar cookiejar.
    See GH #3579
    """
    cj = cookiejar_from_dict({'foo': 'bar'}, cookielib.CookieJar())
    s = requests.Session()
    # ...

def test_headers_on_session_with_None_are_not_sent(self, httpbin):
    """Do not send headers in Session.headers with None values."""
    ses = requests.Session()
    ses.headers['Accept-Encoding'] = None
    # ...
```

Note that you can see these docstrings on the console with the *increased `verbosity`*. Demo:

```
$ cat test_module.py
import unittest


class BasicTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

    def test_two(self):
        """Extended description"""
        self.assertEqual(2, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

$ python -m unittest -v test_module
test_one (test_module.BasicTestSuite) ... ok
test_two (test_module.BasicTestSuite)
Extended description ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```